# Using jQuery and pre-populating an input field rendered by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a form that is embedded into my site using Javascript. I normally pre-populate HTML form fields using .val() from jQuery, but it looks like I cannot do this since the form is rendered by Javascript as well. Is there a way for my jQuery code to interact with the HTML rendered by the Javascript embed?

Comment: Can we see some of the relevant code?

Comment: You can call `.val()` to fill in the fields after you embed it.

Comment: you could populate your form when you are rendering it but can't really say much more until we see some code.

Comment: Can't manipulate an element until it exists. Once it exists the approach is the same

Comment: Delegate the fill event to the non-existent element. Then when it become available it should fill.